# Why does this Python 3.3 code not work? digc not defined

Tags: python, defined

It prints diga and digb but doesnt work with c!  Any help?  It's supposed to be a Denary to Binary converter but only 1-64, once i've cracked the code will increase this!  Thanks so much

```
denaryno=int(input("Write a number from 1-64 "))
if 64%denaryno > 0:
    diga=0
    remaindera=(64%denaryno)
    if 32/denaryno<1:
        digb=1
        remainderb=(denaryno%32)
    else:
        digb =0
        if 16/remainderb<1:
            digc=1
            remainderc=(denaryno%16)
        else:
            digc=0
            if 8/remainderc<1:
                digd=1
                remainderd=(denaryno%8)
            else:
                digd=0
                if 4/remainderd<1:
                    dige=1
                    remaindere=(denary%4)
                else:
                    dige=0
                    if 2/remaindere<1:
                        digf=1
                        remainderf=(denary%2)
                    else:
                        digf=0
                        if 1/remainderf<1:
                            digg=1
                            remainderg=(denary%1)
                        else:
                            digg=0
print (str(diga)+str(digb))
```

Comment: supposed to be whatever number they typed in binary.  For example, if they typed in 50 Output should be 0110010

Comment: You should try doing this recursively, or in a loop / use mapping (dictionaries) this code is very unreadable.

Comment: May I suggest the built-in function `bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that was a lot of work, you don't have to do all that.

```
def bin_convert(x, count=8):
    return "".join(map(lambda y:str((x>>y)&1), range(count-1, -1, -1)))
```

here are the functions comprising this one from easy->important

`str()` returns a string

`range()` is a way to get a list from 1 number to another.  Written like this `range(count-1, -1, -1)` counts backwards.

`"".join()` is a way to take an iterable and put the pieces together.

`map()` is a way to take a function and apply it to an iterable.

`lambda` is a way to write a function in 1 line.   I was being lazy and could have written another `def func_name(y)` and it would have worked just as well.

`>>` is a way to shift bits.  (which I believe understanding this one is the key component to understanding your problem)

Comment: Any chance of comments on the code? I'm not too familiar with these new functions

Answer (score 3):

You only set `digc` in *one* of the top `if`/`else` statement. If `32/denaryno<1` is `True`, you don't set `digc` at all.

Set `digc` at the top of the function (to `0` or whatever else you want it to be). This applies to *all* the digit variables, `digd`, `dige`, etc.

What you *really* should do, instead, is use a list of digits, and append either a 0 or a 1 to that list every time you divide the number by a factor.

You may want to take a look at the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod); it returns both the quotient and the remainder. You could also do with some looping here to slash the number of `if` statements needed here:

```
number = int(input("Write a number from 1-64 "))
digits = []
factor = 64
while number:
    quotient, number = divmod(number, factor)
    digits.append(quotient)
    factor //= 2
print(''.join(map(str, digits)))
```

Comment: Right, i dont understand that, im a real novice.  Apologies.  Any chance of an example line?

Comment: Thank you Mr Pieters, i know my code is highly inefficient.. But, is there any way i could get it to work without adding extra functions and just toggling with as little as possible?

Comment: @user2942083: I gave you all that you need to make your function work in my answer now; but I urge you to at least think about using a list instead.